# OpenGL Transforming an object on it's local coordinate system based on rotation

Tags: opengl, matrix, rotation, translation, coordinate-systems

So at the moment am working on a game for my coursework which is based around the idea of flying a rocket, I spent too much time thinking about the physics behind it that I completely ignored getting it to move properly.
For example when I were to draw a cone with the top pointing to the sky, and I rotate it on the X axis it rotates properly however if I translate it on the Y axis it moves on the global Y axis instead on it's local coordinate system which would have the Y axis pointing out of the cone's top.
My question is does openGL have a local coordinate system or would I have to somehow make my own transformation matrices, and if so how would I go about doing that.

The way I am doing the transformation and rotation is as follows:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(llmX, llmY + acceleration, llmZ);
    glRotatef(rotX, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(rotY, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    drawRocket();
glPopMatrix();
```

Here is a picture better explaining what I mean hopefully offers a better explanation.
[image]

EDIT: I find it really weird that the rotations seem to work one after the other as in if I rotate it on the X axis once and then proceed to rotate it on the Z axis it rotates from the already rotated X axis instead of the world X axis.

Hoping somebody could help me with understanding this, really need to get it working for my project.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a translation matrix for moving up (i.e. moving in positive Y direction), no matter where you are in on the matrix stack or in the transformation process, you are going to move the vertices in the positive Y direction.

If you instead want it move in the rotated direction, I suggest translating along the Y axis ***first***, and then rotate to your desired angle. Essentially, push the matrices in the opposite fashion.

Comment: That does indeed work, and once it's rotated it transforms on the rotated axis, however it does not rotate around it's own axis any more and it seems like it's rotating around the (0,0,0) world coordinate, if somehow the rotation would be made to rotate around it's own axis everything would be solved.

Comment: @MichaelCross Yes thats right, all rotations happen around 0,0,0 even if the object is translated away from the origin. To get rotation around it's own axis, apply the rotations before you do any translation, while the axis is at the origin.

Comment: Took a long time to get back to it, still having the same problem tried a few ways of doing the movement and rotation and I still can't get it to work properly... either it rotates on it own axis but translates on the global axis or it rotates on the global axis but moves on the local axis.